# How to affect a dict item to a variable in django template

Tags: django, templates

i'm trying to affect an item list in template using `{% with %}{% endwith %}` but still get nothing in my varibale
this is the code

```
{% for item in data %}
    <tr>    
    {% with value = item.user_id %}
    {% endwith %}   
<td><a href="{% url accounts value %}"><center>{{ item.Company_name }}</center></a></td>
```

i get this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /filter/

Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the view name in quotes:

```
{% url "accounts" value %}
```

Comment: thinks it works..i thought i don't need to put quotes with django 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Move the `{%endwith%}` after `</td>` tag as below.

```
{% for item in data %}
        <tr>    
          {% with value = item.user_id %}

              <td><a href="{% url accounts value %}"><center>{{ item.Company_name }}</center>
              </a></td>

          {% endwith %}
```

Scope of variable defined using `with` is only within the `with` block.

Comment: thanks now i can assign value to item.user_id but still get an error
Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: urls.py
                       url(r'^accounts/(?P<value>[-\w]+)/$','Our_MarketPlace.views.his_account', name='accounts'),
veiws.py
def his_account(request,value):
    for item in CompanyProfile.objects.filter(user_name_id=value).values() :
        Company_name = item['Company_name']
    return render_to_response('hisprofile.html', {'Company_name':Company_name,'value':value,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))